# Adding user input to an array and updating option list

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have this page:

I have a list that is made from items in array. If user adds new food the input should go to the array and show new item in the list and the input field should dissapear. Right now I am getting 404 error.

How can I do this?

```js
// find elements
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var button = $("button")

var select = document.getElementById("selectFood");
var options = ["Pizza", "Hambruger", "Salad"];

for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
  var opt = options[i];
  var el = document.createElement("option");
  el.textContent = opt;
  el.value = opt;
  select.appendChild(el);
}

function foodInput() {
  boxvalue = document.getElementById('addedFood').value;
  options.push(boxvalue);
}

function addFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #778899;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}


button {
  background: #A52A2A;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

.addButton {
  background: #A52A2A;
  color: white;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.demo {
  background: #A52A2A;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#myDIV {
  background: #778899;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  display: none;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background: #A52A2A;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>My favorite food</p>
  <select id="selectFood">
    <option>Select food</option>
  </select>
  <button>Choose</button>
  <br>
  <button id="addButton" onclick="addFunction();">
    Add new food
  </button>
</div>

<div id="myDIV">
  <form onsubmit="return foodInput()">
    <input type="text" id="addedFood" placeholder="Type food">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="addFunction()">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I think the problem was with the form trying to reload the fiddle Html page on submit.

Here is the working link of the modified content with some little optimization.

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/8rvax5z0/3/]
```

Answer (score 1):

Enjoy!

```js
var options = ["Pizza", "Hambruger", "Salad"];

document.querySelector("form#addFoodForm").onsubmit=function(){
  let existingFoods=document.querySelector("#selectFood");
  const newFood=this.querySelector("input#addedFood").value;
  
  const newFoodOption=document.createElement("option");
        newFoodOption.setAttribute("value", newFood);
        newFoodOption.innerHTML=newFood;
  existingFoods.append(newFoodOption);

  refreshFoodOptions(); // This function will add the new foods into the global 'options' array !

  return false;
}

function refreshFoodOptions(){
  const selectInpt=document.querySelector("#selectFood");
  selectInpt.querySelectorAll("option[value]").forEach(function(food){
    if(!in_array(food.value, options)) options.push(food.value);
  });
  console.log( options );
  return options;
}

function in_array(key, array){
  let exists=false;
  array.forEach(function(arrayKey){
    if(arrayKey==key) exists=true;
  });
  return exists;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>My favorite food</p>
  <select id="selectFood">
    <option>Select food</option>
  </select>
  <button>Choose</button>
</div>

<div id="myDIV">
  <form id="addFoodForm">
    <input type="text" id="addedFood" placeholder="Type food">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new method to refresh options after input like:

```
function refreshFoodInput(options) {
    select.removeChild("option");
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
      var opt = options[i];
      var el = document.createElement("option");
      el.textContent = opt;
      el.value = opt;
      select.appendChild(el);
    }
}
```

Then call this method in foodInput method like

```
function foodInput() {
  var boxvalue = document.getElementById('addedFood').value;
  options.push(boxvalue);
  refreshFoodInput(options);
}
```

Now your whole code will be like:

```
// find elements
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var button = $("button")

var select = document.getElementById("selectFood");
var options = ["Pizza", "Hambruger", "Salad"];
refreshFoodInput(options);

function refreshFoodInput(options) {
    select.removeChild("option");
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
      var opt = options[i];
      var el = document.createElement("option");
      el.textContent = opt;
      el.value = opt;
      select.appendChild(el);
    }
}

function foodInput() {
  var boxvalue = document.getElementById('addedFood').value;
  options.push(boxvalue);
  refreshFoodInput(options);
}

function addFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

Hope you get it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I could completely redo your code to modernize and reduce it but this is not the idea of the question then I just fixed with this:

- Call the options generator (for) when you finishing the push on array because you need to display the new array (select options).
- To do it you need to create a function that executes the for and call on first load and every time when new food was added.
- Empty the select before add options to prevent duplicated options.

Se the code below:

```js
// find elements
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var button = $("button")

var select = document.getElementById("selectFood");
var options = ["Select Food", "Pizza", "Hambruger", "Salad"];

function generateSeletc(foodArray) {
  $('#selectFood').empty();
  for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var opt = options[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
      select.appendChild(el);
  }
}

function foodInput(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  boxvalue = document.getElementById('addedFood').value;
  options.push(boxvalue);
  generateSeletc(options);
}

function addFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}

generateSeletc(options);
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #778899;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}


button {
  background: #A52A2A;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

.addButton {
  background: #A52A2A;
  color: white;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.demo {
  background: #A52A2A;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#myDIV {
  background: #778899;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  display: none;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background: #A52A2A;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>My favorite food</p>
  <select id="selectFood">
    <option>Select food</option>
  </select>
  <button>Choose</button>
  <br>
  <button id="addButton" onclick="addFunction();">
    Add new food
  </button>
</div>

<div id="myDIV">
  <form onsubmit="return foodInput(event)">
    <input type="text" id="addedFood" placeholder="Type food">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="addFunction()">
  </form>
</div>
```